# Java TreeMap with custom class (Long, Date) as Key to sort by Date, but put/get by Long

Tags: java, treemap, comparable

I have a specific problem. I need to create a map of objects identified by a custom Index class consisting of two fields: Long id and Date date. Is it possible to make TreeMap sorted by the date field, but have .containsKey check the id field?

```java
public class Index implements Comparable<Index> {
    public Long id;
    public Date date;

    public Index(Long id, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this. Date = date;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Index i) {
        return date.compareTo(i.date);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Index) {
            Index i = (Index) o;
            return id.equals(i.id);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And code:

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Map<Index,Object> items = new TreeMap<>();
items.put(new Index(10L, formatter.parse("2023-03-14 10:00")), 10L);
items.put(new Index(20L, formatter.parse("2023-03-14 08:00")), 20L);
```

And what I want to achieve is:

1. items.containsKey(10L) should check if there is an Index object with id == 10L.
2. items.put should work normally, so that Index objects can be added normally.
3. items should be sorted by the date field in the Index object, so the 20L will be the first item, and 10L will be the second item.

Comment: I definitely recommend you do not use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those class are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Use `LocalDateTime` or another appropriate class from [java.time. the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: At first `10L` is a value in that map instead of a key. Use `items.containsValue(10L)` to check if vaule does contain in that map or chance key-value order.
Finally, could you provide any piece of code your endeavour to solve the problem?

Comment: No, what you ask is not possible. You may want to use two maps, for example a `HashMap<Id, Index>` and a `TreeMap<LocalDateTime, <Collection<Index>>`.

Comment: Do you just want to be able to access a date by a particular integer number? If so, you are working *much* too hard. I find your Question impossible to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for making your own container class, instead of relying directly on a Map:

```
public class IndexSet {
    private final Map<Long, Index> indexes = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean contains(long id) {
        return indexes.containsKey(id);
    }

    public Index get(long id) {
        return indexes.get(id);
    }

    public void add(Index index) {
        return indexes.put(index.getId(), index);
    }

    public List<Index> allByDate() {
        List<Index> list = new ArrayList<>(indexes.values());
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Index::getDate));
        return list;
    }
}
```